# Opposite signal in the indicator

Tags: pine-script

The indicator places a signal (opens a position). If the open position turned out to be wrong and the asset price went in the opposite direction, how can I make it so that when the price changes by 2% (as a default example), the indicator opens a opposite position? (reverse event).

I am attaching a picture. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the code for a simple indicator:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Buy and Sell Indicator with EMA and MACD", shorttitle="BSI-EMA-MACD", overlay=true)

// EMA
ema20 = ta.ema(close, 20)
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)

// MACD
[macdLine, signalLine, _] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)

// Calculation of prices for buying and selling, taking into account an increase/decrease of 2%
bLong = close * 1.02
nLong = close * 0.98
sShort = close * 0.98
nShort = close * 1.02

// Terms of purchase and sale
buy_condition = ta.crossover(macdLine, signalLine) and ema20 > ema50  
sell_condition = ta.crossunder(macdLine, signalLine) and ema20 < ema50  

// Placement of a triangle on the chart for sale
plotshape(sell_condition ? sShort : na, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.red, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, offset=-1)

// Placement of a triangle on the chart to buy
plotshape(buy_condition ? bLong : na, style=shape.triangledown, color=color.green, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, offset=-1)
```

[image: Visualization on the graph]

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get a buy or sell signal, store the price in a `var` variable. Then  use them to see if there is a reversal.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Buy and Sell Indicator with EMA and MACD", shorttitle="BSI-EMA-MACD", overlay=true)

// EMA
ema20 = ta.ema(close, 20)
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)

// MACD
[macdLine, signalLine, _] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)

// Calculation of prices for buying and selling, taking into account an increase/decrease of 2%
bLong = close * 1.02
nLong = close * 0.98
sShort = close * 0.98
nShort = close * 1.02

// Terms of purchase and sale
buy_condition = ta.crossover(macdLine, signalLine) and ema20 > ema50  
sell_condition = ta.crossunder(macdLine, signalLine) and ema20 < ema50  

var float buy_price = na
var float sell_price = na

buy_price := sell_condition ? na : buy_condition ? close[1] : buy_price
sell_price := buy_condition ? na : sell_condition ? close[1] : sell_price

plot(buy_price, "Buy Price", color.green, 1, plot.style_circles, offset=-1)
plot(sell_price, "Sell Price", color.red, 1, plot.style_circles, offset=-1)

buy_reverse = false
sell_reverse = false

if ((not na(buy_price)) and (close < (buy_price * 0.98)))
    buy_reverse := true

if ((not na(sell_price)) and (close > (sell_price * 1.02)))
    sell_reverse := true

buy_price := buy_reverse ? na : buy_price
sell_price := sell_reverse ? na : sell_price

plotshape(sell_reverse, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.orange, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small)
plotshape(buy_reverse, style=shape.triangledown, color=color.blue, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small)

// Placement of a triangle on the chart for sale
plotshape(sell_condition ? sShort : na, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.red, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, offset=-1)

// Placement of a triangle on the chart to buy
plotshape(buy_condition ? bLong : na, style=shape.triangledown, color=color.green, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, offset=-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Figured it out. Working. Thanks for the help.